# how to generate reports from document library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i want to generate reports(like charts) from document library. either by using javascript or CAML queries or any custom coding. please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have asked for suggestion. Then here are my suggestions for you...

Document Libraries are just like List at the end of the day with the exception that they store document and files. You can develop a custom web-part with .Net Chart Control 3.5 wherein you can query the target document library and generate charts like pie chart, bar chart, etc.

Direct Report generation is not available as a feature in SharePoint but yes you can always query document library with C# (SharePoint Object Model), CAML, jQuery/JavaScript and generate reports/charts.

I hope you may be aware of the out of the box chart web-part available in SP 2010 that can be configured to pull data from any library or list.

The most simple approach would be to create views and filter the library. You can also use Data View web-part and create a simple view that looks like a report by querying the document library with simple configuration and settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can export document libraries in SharePoint but generating reports like charts isn't included yet as a feature however you can use third party tools for that I guess otherwise it going to be a big project to handle.

Comment: the report contains documents with metadata. and in the report i want only certain documents within specific period. let's say from 04th oct to 11th oct i want to display in the report.